# How to programmatically disable buttons or add/remove items from dropDown with Office Ribbon UI

Tags: c++, com, vsto, ms-office, ribbon

I have written a simple C++ COM Office add-in that loads a ribbon XML definition and displays a simple ribbon tab. It features some buttons and a dropDown (combobox/droplist). I can handle button click events and combo selection change events like a charm.

Now I want to update ribbon UI according to changes in the active document so that some buttons are disabled and some items added/removed from combobox.

I have searched up and down and could not find a way to control this. Am I missing something very obvious? How can I change button enabled state from anywhere in my code?

Answer (score 4):

The way I've seen it done, using the Windows Ribbon control: the extra buttons must be specified in the XML markup, at design time. At runtime, you call `SetModes()` to specify which sets of widgets gets displayed in the ribbon.

Like this:

```
  <Application.Views>
    <Ribbon>
      <Ribbon.Tabs>
        <Tab CommandName="cmdTabMain" ApplicationModes="0,1">
          <Group CommandName="cmdGroupCommon" 
                 SizeDefinition="ThreeButtons" 
                 ApplicationModes="0,1">
            <Button CommandName="cmdButtonNew" />
            <Button CommandName="cmdButtonOpen" />
            <Button CommandName="cmdButtonSave" />
          </Group>
          <Group CommandName="cmdGroupSimple" 
                 SizeDefinition="TwoButtons" 
                 ApplicationModes="0">
            <Button CommandName="cmdButtonSwitchToAdvanced" />
            <Button CommandName="cmdButtonDropA" />
          </Group>
          <Group CommandName="cmdGroupAdvanced" 
                 SizeDefinition="FourButtons" 
                 ApplicationModes="1">
            <Button CommandName="cmdButtonSwitchToSimple" />
            <Button CommandName="cmdButtonDropA" />
            <Button CommandName="cmdButtonDropB" />
            <Button CommandName="cmdButtonDropC" />
          </Group>
        </Tab>
      </Ribbon.Tabs>
    </Ribbon>
  </Application.Views>
```

Then (in C# anyway) in the click handler, you do `_ribbon.SetModes(1)` or `_ribbon.SetModes(0)`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! You really put an effort into this but it's not exactly what I was looking for. I was looking specifically for a C++ solution. My problem is I am not sure how to get some `IButton` interface for a specific button in a ribbon and call its `IButton->Enable(false)` method. I hope it makes it clearer now.